# How to have get_or_create() save an object, even if object.attribute passed in doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, object, model, save

I have a function:

```
podcast_instance = Show.objects.get_or_create(title=parsed_podcast.title
                                            day_published=parsed_podcast.day_published     )
```

It's getting the data from an object (parsed_podcast) being passed in. It has a large number of attributes, depending on the podcast, some are there and some are not. I have a lot of datasources being passed into the 'Podcast' object, so I'd like for my function to save what is available, and if there is nothing available, or 'parsed_podcast object has no attribute x' then to just save 'nothing' into that attribute and carry on. The model Show allows for these attributes to have no value.

However, get_or_create just throws an AttributeError and stops, and if I put it in a Try block and print the error this way:

```
try:
        podcast_instance = Show.objects.get_or_create(title=parsed_podcast.title)

except AttributeError:
     Exception
```

It still does not save the data. How can I create an object and just save what is available?

Comment: What attribute error? Show the full thing. And also show the what `parsed_podcast` is. Why is it an object rather than a dict, for example?

Comment: It's coming from a parsed podcast feed - it's a library I'm using. The object is made from an xml/rss feed, and it gives me lots of attributes I can use for my database. When get_or_create tries to create a new object FROM parsed.podcast, if a particular attribute isn't present (which is likely) it throws:

AttributeError: 'Podcast' object has no attribute 'day_published'

Or perhaps AttributeError: 'Podcast object has no attribute 'link'

Comment: That sounds like a very badly-designed library then. You shouldn't have to guess what attributes an object has.

Comment: Those attributes are always there, but if the podcast it's parsing doesn't have that particular attribute, i guess it doesn't save it to the object. Perhaps it's worth looking at the code and seeing if I can get it to always save an attribute with a value no matter what...?

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeError` is because you are accessing the tuple returned by `get_or_create`, not the object.

Use:

```
podcast_instance, created = Show.objects.get_or_create(title=parsed_podcast.title
                  day_published=parsed_podcast.day_published)
```

and you are good to go. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)